# Is there a way to get private projects using jredmine API?

Tags: rest, redmine

I wonder if there is a way to get all private projects using the [jredmine](https://nuiton.org/projects/jredmine) REST API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short anwser: No this is not still possible.

But there is an [open issue](https://nuiton.org/issues/3791) to do this. I will try to this soon.

Comment: Can't wait to get this feature.